# Android - Setting wallpaper using Ion library

Tags: android, android-ion, android-wallpaper

I'm using Ion library for loading image into Imageview.

```
Ion.with(this)
   .load(imageURL)
   .intoImageView(imageview);
```

I want to set loaded image in wallpaper via Intent
this code :

```
Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(imageview);
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
emailIntent.setDataAndType(bmpUri, "image/*");
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

This code worked in picasso library but in Ion library the Uri is empty.

What should i do for getting image Uri from Imageview?